# RecursiveDirectoryIterator error joomla

Tags: joomla, xampp

Im getting an error that i have now idea hove to solve.
Im getting this error after saving a slider images for my joomla page:
`RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\xampp\htdocs\bondenssliderDSimagesDS,C:\xampp\htdocs\bondenssliderDSimagesDS):`

How do i solve this?

Comment: You need to give a lot more information about what you are doing.  You may be better off at [joomla.se] since this doesn't sound like a coding problem but even there you need to explain what you did and what you tried to fix it (such as what you learned by Googling the message). it's not even an error message, it's just a line of PHP. Are you positive there is not a message as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you have a problem with "DS constant". As per Joomla documentation DS(directory Separator) constant has been removed from version 3.x. If you are using any custom component which uses "DS" then it will generate error as it's not defined in the library. To resolve this issue either you can tried to define :

```
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

added to main .php file of components/plugin or module.

Or you can directly install following plugin:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/ds-constant